# Delete a self object of a function [corona sdk]

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a little problem and I'm searching for an easy solution,

in my game, if a bullet touches a specific ennemy, this target should be deleted and respawn otherwhere,

I'm using the self-collision event to make the instructions single to each ennemy, 

the problem is that self-collision function only works if he recognise the target, but as I delete it the first time in my collision function, that ennemy doesn't exist anymore for my function. It works only the first time.

I hope that my problem is understandable,


here is an example of the code:

```
local ennemy
ennemy = display.newRect(0,0, 20, 50)
transition.to( ennemy, {time = 2000, x = 240, y = 160} )

local function onCollision(self,event)
    display.remove( bullet )
    display.remove( ennemy )

    ennemy = display.newRect(0,0, 20, 50)
    transition.to( ennemy, {time = 2000, x = 240, y = 160} )
end

ennemy.collision = onCollision
ennemy:addEventListener( "collision", ennemy )
```

Comment: I am sure that a lot of Corona fans (beer fans?) would love to help you. Posting a code sample showing what you have coded so far, and what is not working, will really help.

Comment: Ok, thank you robnick, I didn't post my code because it's way too long, but I'll try to remake a code just too show my problem. Corona sdk is an easy mobile developing platform ;) Check it out! http://coronalabs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only do `addEventListener()` for the first enemy object, after a collision you have a brand new enemy object which also needs to have it's collision listener setup.

```
local onCollision -- forward declare onCollision() so we can use it from addEnemy()
local enemy

local function addEnemy()
    enemy = display.newRect(0,0, 20, 50)

    -- new object so need to assign collision listener again
    enemy.collision = onCollision
    enemy:addEventListener( "collision", enemy )

    transition.to( enemy, {time = 2000, x = 240, y = 160} )
end

local function onCollision(self,event)
    display.remove( bullet )
    display.remove( enemy )

    addEnemy() 
end

-- Add first enemy…
addEnemy()
```